Add all members of a group as reviewers of a pull request azure DevOps
When creating a pull request in Azure DevOps, I must manually add reviewers. I want to add all reviewers that belong to an Entra Group. I tried to add the group, but it does not consider each member individually and considers that the group must approve the PR. The current policy is that at least one of the members must approve the PR, so I want to add all members and have one of them at least approve.

Hi @LuizViola, Have you got a chance to check the answers below to enable an AAD group member to vote to approve a PR on behalf of the group? Hope the suggestions may help resolve your query in this post. Thx.

In addition to RUI's suggestion to automatically include code reviewers, based on your description, I could reproduce your issue when I was recently added as a new member of an Microsoft Entra (formerly Azure Active Directory) group.
Taking my test below for example, I was the member of both the AADGROUP-RootOwners and AADGROUP1, while I just joined AADGROUP1 in minutes. When I voted to Approve a PR, I only approved on behalf of the AADGROUP-RootOwners leaving no review yet by anyone in AADGROUP1.

According to this document,

Azure DevOps updates Microsoft Entra group membership every hour, but it may take up to 24 hours for Microsoft Entra ID to update dynamic group membership.

I tried to create another AADGROUP-Reviewers and add it as one of the PR required reviewers for a test. When I voted to approve the PR, this time, the AADGROUP1 entitlement seemed to get synchronized.

Considering,

If any changes get made to the Microsoft Entra ID group membership, these changes show up in the next re-evaluation of the group rules, which can be done on-demand, when a group rule gets modified, or automatically every 24 hours.

At last, I tried to Re-evaluate the organization group rules in Organization Settings -> Users, and my vote to approve this PR had represented all the AAD groups.


Please also note that I am not the only member in those groups; thus any member rather than all of them of the AAD group can vote to approve the PR on behalf of the group. And also any reject will change the group vote status to be Rejected.


If the reviewers of pull requests in a specific repository/branch are usually the same, consider adding a branch policy and configure the included code reviewers.
Example:

Please note that if you select Required  pull requests can't be completed until:

Every individual added as a reviewer approves the changes.
At least one person in every group added as a reviewer approves the changes.
If only one group is required, the minimum number of members you specify approve the changes.

